# JsonConvert.SerializeObject Turning Double Into String

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm passing in an object to JsonConvert.SerializeObject, in hopes of turning said object into a json string for use with an API....before serialization this is what the object looks like:

```
var hotelBedsSearchRequest = new HotelBedsSearchRequest()
            {
                stay = new Stay
                {
                    checkIn = "2016-06-08",
                    checkOut = "2016-06-10",
                    shiftDays = "2"
                },
                occupancies = new Occupancy[]
                {
                    new Occupancy
                    {
                        rooms = 1,
                        adults = 2,
                        children = 1,
                        paxes = new Pax[]
                        {
                            new Pax
                            {
                                type = "AD",
                                age = 30
                            },
                            new Pax
                            {
                                type = "AD",
                                age = 30
                            },
                            new Pax
                            {
                                type = "CH",
                                age = 8
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                geolocation = new Geolocation
                {
                    longitude = 2.646633999999949,
                    latitude = 39.57119,
                    radius = 20,
                    unit = "km"
                }
            };
```

All fields serialize fine except for latitude and longitude which when I serialize to a JSON string and view as json in visual studio looks like this:

[image]

Why is the lat and long coming out as a string? It is specified as a double type in the class schema...i've tried both most common serializing techniques (Newtonsoft and built in) both do the same thing...when I run the API i get a 400 error bad request and I'm thinking it's this misrepresentation of the lat and long data type...not sure though and any help would be amazing!

Here is Geolocation class:

```
    public class Geolocation
{
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public int radius { get; set; }
    public string unit { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the serialized JSON output as text:

```
{"stay":{"checkIn":"2016-06-08","checkOut":"2016-06-10","shiftDays":"2"},"occupancies":[{"rooms":1,"adults":2,"children":1,"paxes":[{"type":"AD","age":30},{"type":"AD","age":30},{"type":"CH","age":8}]}],"geolocation":{"longitude":2.6466341018676758,"latitude":39.571189880371094,"radius":20,"unit":"km"},"adults":0}
```

And here is the serialization and API call:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(request);
var response = client.UploadString(endpoint, "POST", json);
var ans = DeserializeResult(response);
```

Comment: did you try appending `f`? like: `longitude = 2.646633999999949f`?

Comment: 1) Can you include the JSON created as text (I.e. copy/paste the result of doing `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(json)`) rather than a screen shot of a visualizer?  2) Can you show us the `Geolocation` class definition?  A class definition is what would be needed for a [complete reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: yes will do, trying appending the f first

Comment: added...and hmmm it appears the lat and long are not converted to strings in this view?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, it had nothing to do with passing in the wrong structure, the request class was simply built wrong...sorry. I didn't realize that even if you don't pass in anything for a field in the schema it will still show when you new up the class